# Some rasterized symbols in math equations with mnsymbol package

Tags: luatex, mnsymbol

I have compiled a document with formulas using Lualatex or Xelatex, and encountered a following issue: some symbols in math equations (like parentheses, root sign, integral sign) are rasterized in the .pdf document (see image below). I can not say that it is badly affects a printed version, but still makes a wrong impression, if you zoom on the document.

The sample code is also provided:

```
\documentclass[unicode, 10pt, a4paper, twoside]{extreport}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} 
\usepackage{MnSymbol} 
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX}]{Times}
\begin{document} 
\begin{equation}
 \nabla \times \vec{H}=-i\omega \varepsilon_0 \varepsilon \vec{E}. \end{equation}
 \begin{equation} \nabla \times \vec{H} =\left( \begin{matrix} -\frac{\partial {H}_y}{\partial z} \\ 0 \\ \frac{\partial {H}_y}{\partial z} \end{matrix} \right) 
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

After compiling the sample code, zoom and look carefully at cross-product sign ("x"), big parentetheses, vector signs, nabla operator (flipped triangle).

After tests I realized that the problem comes from mnsymbol package.

Did someone manage to fix it?

I am using MiKTeX 2.9, under Windows 7.

[image].

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add an example of code producing that output and also some details about your TeX distribution?

Comment: Are you under MiKTeX?

Comment: @SvyatoslavKharitonov -- you can add the information to your question, where it can be nicely formatted.  (you can always edit your own questions.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton -- Thank you very much :)

Comment: I have asked a friend of mine to complile the sample on Mac (!). The symbols in the resulted file are smooth without aliasing. So, it might be a problem of the platform too.

Comment: Does it work (with lualatex) if you add `\usepackage{luatex85}
\pdfmapfile{=MnSymbol.map}`? If yes then your map-files are probably not up-to-date. Run on a command line `updmap`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, indeed, this line helps! And after updating map-files, it seems to work even without this additional package.
Great thanks for the help! :)